# How to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext (Spring framework) to load configuration class during unit test

Tags: java, spring, configuration, junit

I use Spring framework 3.0.5 to build a web application. I use @Configuration annotation to configure my domain object, and some of the domain objects are with session scope. And when I write a unit test using jUnit 4.8.2, the `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` variable cannot get the beans which are defined in configuration class.

I always get the following exceptions:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'country' is defined
```

Is there anyone who can give me some advice for this problem? Thanks a lot!

Here is my configuration class, unit test class, DAO class and domain object class. (I use annotation to configure the app instead of xml)

**Configuration class:**

```java
@Configuration
public class RegionDomainObj
{

 /**
  *  Define City Domain Object bean
  */
 @Bean
 @Scope("session")
 public CityImp city()
 {
  return new CityImp();
 }

 /**
  *  Define City IP Domain Object bean
  */
 @Bean
 @Scope("session")
 public CityIPImp cityIP()
 {
  return new CityIPImp();
 }

 /**
  *  Define Country Domain Object bean
  */
 @Bean
 @Scope("session")
 public CountryImp country()
 {
  return new CountryImp();
 }

 /**
  *  Define Country IP Domain Object bean
  */
 @Bean
 @Scope("session")
 public CountryIPImp countryIP()
 {
  return new CountryIPImp();
 }

 /**
  *  Define Locale Domain Object bean
  */
 @Bean
 @Scope("session")
 public LocaleImp locale()
 {
  return new LocaleImp();
 }

 /**
  *  Define Region Domain Object bean
  */
 @Bean
 @Scope("session")
 public RegionImp region()
 {
  return new RegionImp();
 }

 /**
  *  Define Top Level Domain Domain Object bean
  */
 @Bean
 @Scope("session")
 public TopLevelDomainImp topLevelDomain()
 {
  return new TopLevelDomainImp();
 }
}
```

**Test super class:**

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestENV 
{
 protected AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext annotationConfigWebApplicationContext;

 @Before
 public void setUp()
 {
  annotationConfigWebApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
  annotationConfigWebApplicationContext.refresh();
 }
}
```

**Unit Test class:**

```java
public class CountryDAOTest extends TestENV
{

 private ICountryDAO countryDAO; 

 private ICountry country;

 @Before
 public void setUpLocalTestENV()
 {
  this.country = (ICountry) this.annotationConfigWebApplicationContext.getBean("country");
  this.countryDAO = (ICountryDAO) this.annotationConfigWebApplicationContext.getBean("crazyamsCountryDAO");
 }

 /* Test save country */
 @Test
 public void testSaveCountry()
 {
   this.country.setCode("AU");
   this.country.setName("Australia");
   this.countryDAO.save(this.country);
         /* ignore the assert functions */
 }
}
```

**Update**

Maybe I make this problem too complex, you know, when we use `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`, we can use the following code to register bean definitions.

```java
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext annotationConfigApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

annotationConfigApplicationContext.register(TestProcessUnitConfig.class, OtherClazz.class);
```

And in my project, I use Spring MVC with annotation support, and I use `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` instead of `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.

Although they are very similar, `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` doesn't provide "register" function.

And I just want to know whether there is another way to register bean definition into `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` or not.

Comment: Format your code using CTRL + K. It is unreadable now. And omit the unimportant parts.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use your @Configuration class in the context constructor:

```java
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext annotationConfigApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RegionDomainObj.class);
```

or with register:

```java
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext annotationConfigApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
annotationConfigApplicationContext.register(RegionDomainObj.class);
```

As far as I know, `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` (with the 'Web') is for JSF things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's the cause but there is one thing that bothers me:

Your exporting `country` as an implementation class:

```
 /**
  * Define Country Domain Object bean
  */
 @Bean @Scope("session") public CountryImp country(){
     return new CountryImp();
 }
```

But reference it as an interface:

```
this.country = (ICountry) this.annotationConfigWebApplicationContext.getBean("country");
```

The more obvious way would be to export it as interface as well:

```
 /**
  * Define Country Domain Object bean
  */
 @Bean @Scope("session") public ICountry country(){
     return new CountryImp();
 }
```

Try and see if that makes a difference. Even if it doesn't, it improves your code.

Answer (score 0):

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named

This error appears when something wrong with your configuration classes. In your case you have to directly define where you beans defined. So, add next codelines after `@Configuration` in your test class:

```java
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes={/*..your configuration classes*/})
@PropertySource(/*.. your possible properties files..*/);
```